# Unity. Не срабатывает анимация при коллизии объектов

Tags: c#, unity3d, анимация

2D-платформер. У персонажа есть следующие анимации: состояние покоя, ходьба, прыжок, в воде, подбор предмета. Никак не могу добиться, чтобы корректно срабатывала последняя анимация (подбор предмета).

Скрипт персонажа:

```
  void Update() 
    {
       if (getProbe)
        {
        StartCoroutine(WaitingProbe());
        }

        if (inWater)
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && isGrounded)
                rb.AddForce(transform.up * jumpHeight, ForceMode2D.Impulse);

            anim.SetInteger("State", 5); //анимация в воде (работает)

            isGrounded = true;
            if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") != 0)
            Flip();
        }

        else
        {
            CheckGround();
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && isGrounded)
            {  
            rb.AddForce(transform.up * jumpHeight, ForceMode2D.Impulse); 
            }
            if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") == 0 && ((isGrounded)))
            {
                anim.SetInteger("State", 1);  //анимация покоя (работает)
            }
            else
            {
                Flip();
                if (isGrounded)
                anim.SetInteger("State", 2); //анимация ходьбы (работает)
            }
        }
    }
    
    void FixedUpdate() 
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * speed, rb.velocity.y);
    }

    void Flip() 
    {
        if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") > 0)
            transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0);
        if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") < 0)
            transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 180, 0);
    }

    void CheckGround()      
    {
        Collider2D[] colliders = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(groundCheck.position, 0.2f);      
        isGrounded = colliders.Length > 1;
        if (!isGrounded)
        anim.SetInteger("State", 3); //анимация прыжка (работает)
    }



    void Probe()
    {
        anim.SetInteger("State", 4); // анимация подбора предмета (не работает)
        speed = 0;
    }

    public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Probe")
        {
            curProbe++;
            getProbe = true;
            Probe();
            Destroy(collision.gameObject);
        }

    IEnumerator WaitingProbe()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(WaitTime);
        speed = 5;
        getProbe = false;
    }
}
```

Я пытаюсь добиться того, чтобы при коллизии персонажа и объекта c тегом **Probe**, персонаж замирал на 2 секунды и в это время исполнялась анимация **State 4** «заглушая» другие анимации. После этого персонаж должен вернуться в обычное состояние через **WaitingProbe**.
Метод  **OnTriggerEnter2D** срабатывает корректно: Вызывает метод **Probe()**, переменная **speed** меняет значение на 0 (персонаж замирает), а вот анимация не меняется.
Самое интересное, что если вместо обычного вызова метода `Probe();` использовать `Invoke(“Probe”, 1f)`, вот тогда анимация проигрывается (с задержкой, которая не требуется). В аниматоре все State и Transition настроены идентично.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём может быть причина? Что я упускаю?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что у вас состояние анимации перезаписывается каждый кадр, а не только при изменении. То есть ваша 4 на следующий кадр уже заменяется другим значением. Добавьте логирование, увидите что скрипт постоянно спамит этими анимациями, даже если вы ничего не делаете. Это огромная куча лишней работы, тормозящей игру.

Для оптимизации создайте метод.

```
private int _state; // 0

private void SetAnimation(int state)
{
    if (state == _state)
        return;
    _state = state;
    anim.SetInteger("State", state);
    Debug.Log($"Set animation: {state}");
}
```

И все вызовы типа `anim.SetInteger("State", 4)` замените на `SetAnimation(4)`. Далее смотрите в консоль Unity и увидите, где у вас сбой в логике.